# Startup lag on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

when users launch my app, I request from websocket the list of session of a chat system.
When the websocket responds to the request, I parse the results to build the session and then i parse the message and add them to the messageList of every Session, like this:

```
    for (NSDictionary *session in sessions) {
      for (NSDictionary *message in messages) {

        ChatMessage *message = [[ChatMessage alloc] init];
        [listOfMessages addObject:message];

       } 
    }
```

This cause a one second lag at startup. How can I reduce It?

EDIT: It tooks the phone's CPU at 100% for some seconds, that's the problem, not a network one because I have all the JSON ready on ad array.

Comment: Are are you using asynchronous requests?

Comment: The speed will depend on the number of items contained in sessions. If that is causing the performance lag, then consider moving the loops to a background thread

Answer (score 0):

> How can I reduce It?

- **Load less up front.** A small network request can usually be performed very quickly; if your startup takes a full second, one way to reduce the wait is to load less with that very first request. Can you load just enough to let the user start using your app for the next four or five seconds?
- **Keep previous data.** Perhaps the data that the app had loaded in the previous session is good enough to let the user proceed for a few seconds. Using that data, even if you have to let the user know that it's being updated, could buy you enough time to refresh the app.
- **Give the user something to do.** If you absolutely can't move forward until the full request has been processed, perhaps you can provide some useful or interesting interaction while the request is happening. Even showing progress while the data is being downloaded could be enough -- anything to prevent the app from looking like it's not doing anything during that initial period.

Comment: Yeah but it's not too much data. It's about 10 chatrooms with 10 messages each. And the problem isn't linked with web request. The lag is when I have the JSONS and I have to serialize It as local custom objects. How can I move It in a background task?

Comment: A user can only look at one chatroom at a time, right? So might make sense to load the one that they're in first, and load the others afterward, or even only when they're needed. You can certainly deserialize the deta in a background task -- you should be loading the data in the background as well. How to do that seems outside the scope of this question, but there's plenty of documentation on background processing.

Answer (score 0):

Call this in a background queue:
1. Use GCD and call `dispatch_async`
2. Create your own `NSOperationQueue` and add a `NSBlockOperation` to it